# Using the orocos/rtt rosparam service in c++

Tags: ros, orocos, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to use the rtt_ros_integration rosparam service from within one of my own components in c++. The only documentation I can find for accessing the interface of a service plugin through c++ requires that the service has a class declaration in some header that can be included: http://www.orocos.org/stable/documentation/rtt/v2.x/doc-xml/orocos-rtt-plugins.html#idp216560

Is there a way to do this by leveraging the rtt operations defined in rtt_rosparam_service.cpp?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32170/using-the-orocos/rtt-rosparam-service-in-c++/) by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5809 on 2012-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you need to do for this particular service is to first load the service:

```
// In your TaskContext subclass:
PluginLoader::Instance()->loadService("rosparam", this);
```

And then you could dynamic_cast the service pointer:

```
boost::shared_ptr<RosParam> rp = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<RosParam>( this->provides("rosparam") );

rp->storeProperties(); // etc.
```

UNFORTUNATELY, this service was implemented fully in the .cpp file, so no header is available. What you can do, if you don't want to submit a patch which creates a nice hpp/cpp file and installs the hpp, you can write this as a workaround:

```
OperationCaller<bool(void)> storeProperties = this->provides("rosparam")->getOperation("storeProperties");

storeProperties(); // calls the Service's Operation.
```

Peter

---

Originally posted by [psoetens](https://answers.ros.org/users/1336/psoetens/) with karma: 76 on 2012-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-04-18**:
Ahh! I see. After loading the plugin, I was trying this->requires("rosparam")->getOperation("storeProperties"). Thanks!